# Why I() "AsIs" is necessary when making a linear polynomial model in R?

Tags: r, polynomial-math

I'm trying to understand what is the role of `I()` base function in R when using a linear polynomial model or the function `poly`. When I calculate the model using

1. `q + q^2`
2. `q + I(q^2)`
3. `poly(q, 2)`

I have different answers.

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(20)
q <- seq(from=0, to=20, by=0.1)
y <- 500 + .1 * (q-5)^2
noise <- rnorm(length(q), mean=10, sd=80)
noisy.y <- y + noise
model3 <- lm(noisy.y ~ poly(q,2))
model1 <- lm(noisy.y ~ q + I(q^2))
model2 <- lm(noisy.y ~ q + q^2)
I(q^2)==I(q)^2
I(q^2)==q^2

summary(model1)
summary(model2)
summary(model3)
```

Here is the output:

```
> summary(model1)

Call:
lm(formula = noisy.y ~ q + I(q^2))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-211.592  -50.609    4.742   61.983  165.792 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 489.3723    16.5982  29.483   <2e-16 ***
q             5.0560     3.8344   1.319    0.189    
I(q^2)       -0.1530     0.1856  -0.824    0.411    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 79.22 on 198 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.02451,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.01466 
F-statistic: 2.488 on 2 and 198 DF,  p-value: 0.08568

> summary(model2)

Call:
lm(formula = noisy.y ~ q + q^2)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-219.96  -54.42    3.30   61.06  170.79 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 499.5209    11.1252  44.900   <2e-16 ***
q             1.9961     0.9623   2.074   0.0393 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 79.16 on 199 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.02117,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.01625 
F-statistic: 4.303 on 1 and 199 DF,  p-value: 0.03933

> summary(model3)

Call:
lm(formula = noisy.y ~ poly(q, 2))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-211.592  -50.609    4.742   61.983  165.792 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  519.482      5.588  92.966   <2e-16 ***
poly(q, 2)1  164.202     79.222   2.073   0.0395 *  
poly(q, 2)2  -65.314     79.222  -0.824   0.4107    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 79.22 on 198 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.02451,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.01466 
F-statistic: 2.488 on 2 and 198 DF,  p-value: 0.08568
```

Why is the `I()` necessary when doing a polynomial model in R.

Also, is this normal that the `poly` function doesn't give the same result as the `q + I(q^2)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula syntax in R is described in the `?formula` help page. The `^` symbol has not been given the usual meaning of multiplicative exponentiation. Rather, it's used for interactions between all terms at the base of the exponent. For example

```
y ~ (a+b)^2
```

is the same as

```
y ~ a + b + a:b
```

But if you do

```
y ~ a + b^2
y ~ a + b    # same as above, no way to "interact" b with itself.
```

That caret would just include the `b` term because it can't include the interaction with itself. So `^` and `*` inside formulas has nothing to do with multiplication just like the `+` doesn't really mean addition for variables in the usual sense.

If you want the "usual" definition for `^2` you need to put it the as is function. Otherwise it's not fitting a squared term at all.

And the `poly()` function by default returns orthogonal polynomials as described on the help page. This helps to reduce co-linearity in the covariates. But if you don't want the orthogonal versions and just want the "raw" polynomial terms, then just pass `raw=TRUE` to your `poly` call. For example

```
lm(noisy.y ~ poly(q,2, raw=TRUE))
```

will return the same estimates as `model1`

Comment: Best explanation I read so far! Also, I would just point out that `lm(noisy.y ~ q + I(q^2))` and `lm(noisy.y ~ poly(q,2, raw=TRUE))` are identical **but** `lm(noisy.y ~ q + I(q)^2)` is not. Because of the explanation you provided. I had the idea that since the object was AsIs, then `^2` would actually square the term but it doesn't. Something to keep in mind for posterity!